# Can't create Godaddy Api key :/ An error occurred on client

Tags: godaddy-api

[image: godaddy api error, An error occurred on client2]

[image: godaddy api error, An error occurred on client]

I mailed 4 time to api@godaddy.com
They replied but has not fixed yet.
Hated from godaddy
How can i solve this problem Thanks
:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godaddy chat confirmed with me as well.
I am so sorry for the delay, please try to create the ApI key after 10-12 hours and it will b working fine (8/31/2022 8:02 AM EST)

Comment: Thank it was fixed by Godaddy :)